# ¿Cómo puedo relacionar un check con un input y que no se combinen sus respectivos inputs si selecciono más de un check?

Tags: php, array, laravel-5, xampp

Estoy trabajando en un un proyecto el cual genera registros de pacientes (como un formulario), en el registro ademas de los datos del paciente, se adjuntan diferentes tipos de documentos (los cuales se muestran como checkbox) que hayan sido seleccionados, y para cada documento seleccionado se le puede agregar de manera opcional un detalle (texto).

[image: ![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al momento de guardar el registro, se le adjuntan los documentos seleccionados y en caso de que este tenga un detalle, este se muestre entre parentesis, como en el siguiente ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Todo bien hasta ahí, el problema ocurre cuando quiero registrar mas de un documento y hay dos casos que se me presentan:

1. Si selecciono dos documentos y solo uno tiene un detalle, el valor de detalle se adjunta para ambos documentos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. Si selecciono dos documentos y los dos tienen un detalle, el valor de detalle se adjunta a ambos documentos y ademas se concadenan formando un solo detalle de ambos, como se muestra a continuación:

[image: ![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

//outputs

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿De qué manera puedo relacionar cada documento con su respectivo detalle y que estos no se adjunten a los demás documentos y mucho menos se concadenen?

la función de guardar es la siguiente:

```
public static function guardarRegistro($paciente, $request)
{
    $request['patient_id'] = $paciente->id; 
    $request['user_id'] = Auth::user()->id; 
    
    $registro = Registry::create($request->all());

    $details = $_REQUEST['details'];
    $documento = $_REQUEST['documento'];
    

    //borra los detalles nulos del array $details (esto porque me mostraba un array con todos los valores, incluido los valores NULL)
    foreach ($details as $detail => $value) {  // Por cada elemento en el array
        if ((is_null($value) || strlen($value) < 1)) { // Si es NULL o no tiene carácteres
            unset($details[$detail]); // Quitar el elemento del array
        }
    }
    
    $detalle = array_values($details);

    $detalle = implode($detalle);   
    

    if (is_null($detalle)) 
    {
        $registro->documentos()->attach($documento);

        $registro->save();
    }

    else {
        $registro->documentos()->attach($documento, ['details' => $detalle]);

        $registro->save();
    }

    return $registro;
}
```

PD:Intenté crear una matriz combinada, donde le paso como indice el valor (id) de documentos y asi poder relacionarlo con su respectivo detalle, sin embargo, si selecciono dos documentos, uno con detalle y el otro no, me arroja el error de que ambos parámetros deben tener el mismo numero de elementos

```
//asigna como indice de la matriz(combi) el id de documentos y como valor $detalle
    $combi = array_combine($documento, $details);
   
    $keys = array_keys($combi); 
    $values = array_values($combi);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradecería mucho si alguien me puede orientar con mi necesidad, que tenga un excelente día todo aquel que se dió el tiempo de leer!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pivotea por documento, y así controlas el detalle de cada uno con un *operador ternario*.

```
foreach( $_REQUEST['documento'] as $i => $doc ){
   $registro->documentos()->attach( $doc
                                  , ( isset( $_REQUEST['details'][$i] )
                                    ? ['details' => $_REQUEST['details'][$i]]
                                    : []
                                    )
                                  );
}
$registro->save();
```

Comment: muchisimas gracias amigo!!